# most visited node after travelling q paths in a graph

Tags: tree, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a tree with n vertices and n-1 edges.I have q queries.In each query I travel the shortest path from a source node to a destination node. Here q,n<=10^5 .I want to know the most visited node after finishing all the queries.I just want to know some algorithm which is fastest in this particular problem.I tried with bfs but it is giving TLE,is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

See there is a single path between 2 nodes in a tree(where nodes don't get repeated). So first do Euler Tour on Tree and then update is like:
say x is lca(u,v)
update-> start(x)->start(u), end(u)->start(v), end(v)->end(x) by +1 where start(u)

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow. The readability improves if styling all code as "code sample".